# How to not open File upload when parameters are not meet javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

How to not open the file upload box when input mytextField is null.

```
       <input type="text" id="mytextField">
    <input type="file" multiple id="myFileUpload">



    <script>
        document.getElementById("myFileUpload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var myTextF = document.getElementById("mytextField");
    if(myTextF = null || myTextF == ''){
    //will not open the file upload
    } else {
    //let the file upload open
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you found your solution in the answers, please mark the answer as the solution so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the upload button when textarea is empty and enable it when textarea contains text.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkField()" id="mytextField">
<input type="file" multiple id="myFileUpload" disabled="disabled">
```

script:

```
function checkField(){
    var myTextF = document.getElementById("mytextField");
    if(myTextF.value.trim() != ""){
        document.getElementById("myFileUpload").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Used the `trim()` function to prevent empty whitespace texts.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are assigning `myTextF` to the element, rather than the `innerText`.
Try with `var myTextF = document.getElementById("myTextF").innerText;`

If something doesn't work, you could always try to log the output to the console.

In this case, because you are assigning the element, that resolves as `TRUE`, and it will always try to open the file.

```
document.getElementById("myFileUpload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var myTextF = document.getElementById("mytextField");
    if(myTextF = null || myTextF == ''){
    //will not open the file upload
    console.log("I should not open file")
    } else {
    //let the file upload open
    console.log("I should open the file")
    }
    });
```

> " I should open the file"